# git workflow for staging deployment with multiple feature branches (aka. easy branch replace)

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, git-workflow

i'm looking for an easy way to make sure one local feature-branch completely 1:1 replaces a a remote deployment branch whereas the deployment branch is nothing else than a vehicle to deploy.

## the setup

### remote

master: deploys to production
stage: deploys to staging

### local developer a

master -> remote master
feature A
feature B

### local developer b

master -> remote master
feature C
feature D

## the question

now let's say developer A wants to show his feature A to the boss. therefore he needs to deploy it on the staging server, to do so he merges his feature A into stage, and pushes and deploys.
but what if now developer A wants to show feature B or developer B wants to show feature C or D. to make sure theres no interference it has to be guaranteed that only one feature is on the server and not two or three.

the only way i know of now is that the deployment branch stage is reverted until it resembles master and then another feature can be merged into it for deployment.
or one could "simply" delete the branch stage and then recreate it from master.

so how can this be achieved easily?
is this in fact a force push?

cheers!

Comment: Yes, you'd have to do forced (non fast-forward) updates of the branches. Habitual use of non fast-forward updates is a warning sign that you're doing something you shouldn't be doing. Locking deployment environments to specific branch names seems like a bad idea. A deployment environment that can pick up code from any branch would solve your problem and in general allow more flexibility.

Comment: i agree but the background is that we use beanstalk and it actually deploys files instead of us having a git repo on the server and switching branches or the like. in beanstalk you have environments with servers and for each env you select one branch to deploy, so in order to deploy you have to get your code in that branch.

Comment: Did anyone manage to find a good solution to this? @greenone83

Comment: @GouravChawla we basically stopped using staging servers, each developer has their own local environment and we simply develop and test there, maintaining a representative staging server in production was too much of a hassle

Comment: Ah, local dev and test works fine if dev is the only one testing it. Business people would need a separate instance to see how it works which is what staging is. I hope that worked out you. It won't really work for me. After some more digging I did find this though which is exactly what I needed: https://github.com/rocketraman/gitworkflow